# support for servicestack ormlite timestamp

Tags: ormlite-servicestack, optimistic-concurrency

is it possible to use SqlServer Timestamp for optimistic concurency in servicestack-ormlite?

currently if I am using it ormlite is trying to update it, I guess I need an attribute to tell ormlite that this is row-version.

if something like this does note exist, I guess it should be not easy to add it, my only question is should it be done with an attribute? if yes where should i put this attribute
thanks